# Why extract “dumb” components into an index.ts ngModule?

Tags: angular

Forgive me if I get terminology wrong, I’m new to Angular.

To make the next paragraph make sense, my understanding is that a container is a “smart” component (where you manage data subscribe/observer etc..) and that other components are referred to as  “dumb” since all they should do is just display data via @input or signal changes via @output…

So with that understanding I’m looking over the [Official @ngrx example application](https://github.com/ngrx/platform/tree/master/projects/example-app) and they are following that pattern. However, I noticed that they use an `index.ts` to “export” the books “dumb” components via a module which kinda acts like a barrel file… my question is why? Is this just a style choice? The repo states that this project is showcasing common patterns and best practices and I wanted to understand this more and i can't seem to find the answer.

Maybe a better way of putting this, why is it preferred to import a module (of components) than to just declare them as they do with the containers?

```
import { dumbModules } from 'blah...'
import { containerOne } from 'blah...'
import { containerTwo } from 'blah...'

@NgModule ({
 imports: [
  ...,
  dumbModules
 ],
 declarations: [
  ...,
  containerOne,
  containerTwo
 ]
})
```

VS

```
import { dumbComponentOne } from 'blah...'
import { dumbComponentTwo } from 'blah...'
import { containerOne } from 'blah...'
import { containerTwo } from 'blah...'

@NgModule ({
imports: [
    ...
],
declarations: [
    ...,
    dumbComponentOne,
    dumbComponentTwo,
    containerOne,
    containerTwo
]
})
```

Or do I still have a lot to understand and I’m missing something obvious here…

Comment: My guess is that dumb components are more likely to be just presentational and thus reused elsewhere. So it's simpler to import a whole module in other places.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Organizing your components in modules have a couple advantages. So does the separation of smart and dumb components.

At Google they stated a while ago they have about 1.5 component per module. Reason is that modules can easily be reused, whereas components can not. Also, modules can be lazy loaded and treeshaken.

The smart and dumb components is a design pattern that results in easier to reuse components. The dumb components can always be reused without worrying about side effects or weird services you need in depth knowledge of. Making them very easy to reuse, means you're most likely going to reuse them one day or another.

A component can only be in one module. Assuming you have feature modules, this means you couldn't reuse functionality across modules. This is highly undesired. A modules though, can be imported in as many other modules as you'd like and the angular compiler is smart enough not to include the code twice in your bundle.

The index file is so you can import modules from the same location. Useful for libraries, and in essence your dumb components is your own component library.

I hope my random listing of some of the reasons makes some sense to you...

Comment: ok this makes sense to me, especially the "component library" part. So just like the popular Angular Material components... you just import their "dumb" components and allows you to use them in multiple places. The reason you don't do this for the containers is that reusing them could introduce side effects. not sure why i couldn't work my way through that one myself. Thanks for you answer i'll mark this as accepted.

Comment: It would work for one feature module. A component can only be declared one, so you simply cannot declare a component in two modules. The compiler simply wouldn't know how to optimize your final bundle if you could. But you can import a module in two modules.